# Cholesterol Lowering Statins

Tags: cholesterol

I heard that taking a statin to lower your LDL cholesterol is not a beneficial as one may think.  Some statins lower all cholesterol.  If the HDL cholesterol is lowered, you may not have enough of it to remove the deposits in your arteries.  This would then NOT lower your chances of having a heart attack or stroke.  Is this true or bunk?

This [video](http://princetonhealthusa.com/video.php) supports this information.

Comment: "I heard" Do you have references? This site is about proving or debunking notable claims.

Comment: That video is painful to watch, unable to be fast-forwarded and doesn't make these claims in the first three minutes (where it cuts out on my phone). Can we do better?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of an existing question. If there is a claim that doesn't match that question, please edit this one to include a specific claim (preferably including an appropriate quote) and flag to be reopened.